# Parsing a plaintext document into a python array

Tags: python, parsing, text-parsing

I was given a text file in this format, in python (the number values could be any decimal values):

```
'Document1',[
    'words_list1',[  
        'word1',[  
            'value1', 4,  
            'value2', 50],  
        'word2',[  
            'value1', 2,  
            'value2', 30], 
         ...
        'wordx',[  
            'value1', 1,  
            'value2', 9]]],
 'Document2',[
    'words_list2',[  
        'word1',[  
            'value1', 1,  
            'value2', 4],  
        'word2',[  
            'value1', 6,  
            'value2', 99], 
         ...
        'wordx',[  
            'value1', 22,  
            'value2', 92]]],
 ...

 'Documentx',[
    'words_listx',[  
        'word1',[  
            'value1', 1,  
            'value2', 4],  
        'word2',[  
            'value1', 6,  
            'value2', 99], 
         ...
        'wordx',[  
            'value1', 22,  
            'value2', 92]]]
```

I would like to parse this into a python array by document, word, and values (i.e. I want to be able to access each value by: array_name[document #][word #][value #].

Any help on how I would go about this would be very helpful -- I am new to python, and am not sure if there are any libraries that would help me do this.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far? `re.split` will probably be helpful, as would `ast.literal_eval` and `dict`

Comment: I'm not aware offhand of any libraries that will parse data written just like this. It's a shame, since whatever produced this data could almost certainly write the data formatted as YAML or JSON, which would be trivial to parse in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word_dic = eval(open("word.txt").read())
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need in libraries, you can just `eval`:

```
doc = """'Document1',[
            'words_list1',[
                'word1',[
                     'value1', 4,
                     'value2', 50],
                 'word2',[
                     'value1', 2,
                     'value2', 30],
                 'wordx',[
                     'value1', 1,
                     'value2', 9]]]"""
>>> d = eval('[{}]'.format(doc))
>>> d
['Document1', ['words_list1', ['word1', ['value1', 4, 'value2', 50], 'word2', ['value1', 2, 'value2', 30], 'wordx', ['value1', 1, 'value2', 9]]]]
```

and converting to dict, conributed by @JoranBeasley

```
def to_dict(l):
    if not isinstance(l[1], list):
       return dict(zip(*[iter(l)]*2))
    rv = zip(*[iter(l)]*2)
    return {k: to_dict(v) for k, v in rv}

>>> to_dict(d)
{'Document1': {'words_list1': {'word1': {'value2': 50, 'value1': 4}, 'wordx': {'value2': 9, 'value1': 1}, 'word2': {'value2': 30, 'value1': 2}}}}
```

Comment: `d = dict(zip(*[iter(d)]*2))`

Answer (score 1):

You can load the file into python like this:

```
text = open('txt_filename').read()
data = eval('[' + text + ']')
```

Then you can count data to get what you want

Comment: ast.literal_eval would probably be better

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `dict` in Python. **Here is simple iterative version:**

```
txt = [ \
    'Document1',[
    'words_list1',[
        'word1',[
            'value1', 4,
            'value2', 50],
        'word2',[
            'value1', 2,
            'value2', 30],
        'wordx',[
            'value1', 1,
            'value2', 9]]],
    'Document2',[
    'words_list2',[
        'word1',[
            'value1', 1,
            'value2', 4],
        'word2',[
            'value1', 6,
            'value2', 99],
        'wordx',[
            'value1', 22,
            'value2', 92]]],
    'Documentx',[
    'words_listx',[
        'word1',[
            'value1', 1,
            'value2', 4],
        'word2',[
            'value1', 6,
            'value2', 99],
        'wordx',[
            'value1', 22,
            'value2', 92]]]]

d = {}
for i in xrange(0,len(txt),2):
    dls = txt[i+1]
    d2 = {}
    for j in xrange(0,len(dls),2):
        wds = dls[j+1]
        d3 = {}
        for k in xrange(0,len(wds),2):
            vls = wds[k+1]
            d4 = {}
            for m in xrange(0,len(vls),2):
                d4[vls[m]] = vls[m+1]
            d3[wds[k]] = d4
        d2[dls[j]] = d3
    d[txt[i]] = d2
```

**results:**

```
>>> d['Documentx']
{'words_listx': {'word1': {'value2': 4, 'value1': 1}, 'wordx': {'value2': 92, 'value1': 22}, 'word2': {'value2': 99, 'value1': 6}}}

>>> d['Documentx']['words_listx']
{'word1': {'value2': 4, 'value1': 1}, 'wordx': {'value2': 92, 'value1': 22}, 'word2': {'value2': 99, 'value1': 6}}

>>> d['Documentx']['words_listx']['word1']
{'value2': 4, 'value1': 1}

>>> d['Documentx']['words_listx']['word1']['value1']
1
```